# Get a list of all open windows using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, window

New to batch files but so far have managed to get some handy tools working. But I have now got stuck on something I taught would be trivial.

I'am now working on a tool that needs to know what windows file explorer has open. I have had a look and all the examples I coming across are about either opening directories or listing content of specified directory. The closest examples I have found for what I'm trying to do are in higher level languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only list the last active Explorer window:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe" /v /fo:csv') do (
    set "info=%%a" & set "info=!info:","=^|!" & set info=!info:~1,-1!
    for /f "delims=| tokens=9" %%b in ("!info!") do if not "%%b"=="N/A" echo %%b
)
pause
```

To list all open Explorer windows you'd have to use [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) utility:

```
for /f "tokens=8*" %%a in ('cmdow /t /b') do if %%a==explorer echo %%b
```

Comment: just trying to get the head around the first piece of code. I thinking of changing my approach to what I'm implementing if I have no luck I will use cmdow.

Comment: The first loop reads tasklist's output by lines, then each line is prepared for parsing by replacing csv delimiters "," with another delimiter to make extraction of the token we need possible, then the opening and closing quotes are stripped. The second loop now can see the tokens in the line separated by `|` and it puts window title into %%b.

Comment: cheers man you really know your batch. I'll give you the chosen answer as I'm probably going to end up using cmdow. After I am finished banging my head against a brick wall for another while of course. who say stubbornness isn't a good quality :)